# How to revive my licuala grandis?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, plant-health, watering

[image]

I was away for two weeks and unfortunately forgot to tell the caretaker to water my licuala grandis while I’m away. When I got back home this is how it looks like

Is there any chance to revive this plant at this stage? I’ve watered it again 3 days ago but there seems to be no sign of improvement